# Unable to create Azure function app in West Germany region - This region has quota of 0 instances

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to create an Azure function app in *West Germany* region, however that fails with:

> This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try
> selecting different region or SKU. (Code:
> SubscriptionIsOverQuotaForSku)

[image]

I could create the Azure Function App in another region, but I want to understand why I am unable to create an Azure Function App in the *West Germany* region.

I already checked the quotas of my subscription, but there I can't find anything about Azure Functions:
[image]

I also checked [Products available by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/?regions=germany-north,germany-west-central&products=functions) which confirms that Azure Functions are available in the *West Germany* region:
[image]

So, why can't I create an Azure Function App in the *West Germany* region?

Comment: It may be that all resources allocated to AF’s in that region are exhausted. Try again tomorrow. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons and resolutions could be followed as @*skin* suggested:

> It may be that all resources allocated to AF’s in that region are exhausted. Try again tomorrow.

Even the Microsoft documentation shows quota available for the products by region, they have certain limits for the Subscription level in terms of Azure Compute Units allocation because the Hardware Configuration of the Function App is not specified.

[image]

You can visit this MS [Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-functions-limits) & [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/acu) for the ACUs Quota allocation per instance and Hosting Plan based.

And also, Same issue registered in Microsoft Q&A Forum #[878011](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/878011/cant-create-function-app-get-this-region-has-quota) where @MayankBargali-MSFT explained the cause of the error you mentioned regarding why quota is limited on the location and subscription level.

Also, you can mail to AzCommunity@microsoft.com by stating your business justification and details for quota increase request along with the Azure Subscription Id, Azure Resource Name and the Issue Time of occurrence in UTC.